# Offset top onload when anchor in URL

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I have smooth anchor scrolling working however it doesn't work when coming from other pages. How can I offset the scroll position due to the fixed header?

Current JS:

```
// to top right away
if ( window.location.hash ) scroll(0,0);
// void some browsers issue
setTimeout( function() { scroll(0,0); }, 1);

$(function() {

    // your current click function
    $('.scroll').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset('100').top + 'px'
        }, 1000, 'swing');
    });

    // *only* if we have anchor on the url
    if(window.location.hash) {

        // smooth scroll to the anchor id
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset('100').top + 'px'
        }, 1000, 'swing');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found Your question - and this is the solution:

```
// *only* if we have anchor on the url
if(window.location.hash) {

    var offset = -100;

    // smooth scroll to the anchor id
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($(window.location.hash).offset().top + offset) + 'px'
    }, 1000, 'swing');
}
```

Customize Your offset value to smoothly scroll to desired place